# How Can I use jEmoji plugin inside DIV not input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I am using jEmoji plugin  [http://franverona.com/jemoji/][1] to show names of emojies inside Div (Rich text editor)

but I am facing problem because the editor not an input, this error appeared

> jemoji.js:133 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of
>   undefined

I tried to replace input with div and value with html, but still I don't know how can I get the length of the div

this the original code

```
  if ($el.length === 0) {
    return 0;
  }

  var input = $el[0], pos = input.value.length;

  try {
    if (input.createTextRange) {
      var r = document.selection.createRange().duplicate();
      r.moveEnd('character', input.value.length);
      if (r.text === '') {
        pos = input.value.length;
      }
      pos = input.value.lastIndexOf(r.text);
    }
    else {
      if (typeof(input.selectionStart) !== 'undefined') {
        pos = input.selectionStart;
      }
    }
  }
  catch (e) {
    // IE bug with createTextRange
  }

  return pos;
};
```

this html code

```
<label style="padding-left: 7px;font-family: Calibri; font-size: 15pt; font-weight: normal; color:#59b258;">English</label>

          <input id="EN">
```

to convert the `<input id="EN">` to rich text editor I used jqte plugin
so now I am treating with div by using the class name inside div I called jemoji function

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('#EN').jqte();
  $('.jqte_editor').jemoji();
});
```

Comment: Provide Html code.

Comment: I edited the post and added jquery and html code, just to clarify